# Unity WebGL UnityWebRequest not working when uploading and downloading data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, unity-networking

I can neither upload data nor download data by communicating with a web server using UnityWebRequest. In my case I am trying to upload and download user high scores (I am using the dreamlo service). Both of the Coroutines below do not work as the Upload Coroutine simply does not upload the desired score, and the Download Coroutine does not return text.

```
IEnumerator UploadHighscore(string name, int score, int gameMode){
        UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest (webURL + privateCode + "/add/" + UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL(name + "+" + score.ToString()) + "/" + score + "/" + gameMode);
        yield return www;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        print("Uploaded");
        uIManager.RegisterCallBack(true);
    }
    else {
        print ("Failed to Upload: " + www.error);
        uIManager.RegisterCallBack(false);
    }
}

IEnumerator DownloadHighscores(){
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get (webURL + publicCode + "/pipe/");
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        FormatHighScores(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Edit: The code works in the Unity Editor. For some reason it only stops working once embedding my WebGL build into my Website.

Comment: And why? Are you getting any error/output? Did you debug to make sure all the URLs are correct?

Comment: @derHugo the URLs are correct, as the code works in the Unity Editor. For some reason it only stops working once embedding my WebGL build into my Website.

Comment: and what are those URLs? and is it possible that it is an firewall/DNS resultion problem on your webpage?

Comment: @derHugo no....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use The WWW class.
If the game doesn't work when compiled, 
send the errors from the console of the browser.